# webpack 3 Error Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-3

I'm trying to make a boilerplate with the newest packages(please don't post a link to a "really good boilerplate", my needs are very specific). I'm trying to upgrade and use webpack 3, I followed the instruction to migrate, I've reach a dead end,things were working well in webpack 1.

Relevant section from package.json

```
"webpack": "^3.11.0"
"foundation-sites": "^6.4.4-rc1",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"node-sass": "^4.7.2",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-router": "^4.2.0"
```

webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';
var webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        'jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min',
        './app/app',
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
        alias: {
            Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
            applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
        },
        extensions: ['*','.js','.jsx','.scss']
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: ['react', 'env']
            }
        },
        {
            test:/\.(s*)css$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            options: {
                includePaths: path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss')
            }
        }
        ]
  },
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
};
```

[image: project structure]

I'm getting this error, when I run webpack

```
ERROR in ./app/app.jsx
Module parse failed: F:\tmp\BP\app\app.jsx Line 13: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| ReactDOM.render(
|     <Router history={hashHistory}>
|         <Route path="/" component={Main}>
|         </Route>
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' C:\Users\andro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\buildin\amd-options.js in F:\tmp\BP\node_modules\jquery\dist
 @ ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 2:86650-86660
```

I believe the problem is probably because of the **resolve.extentions**, I tried to add **the empty string, but webpack3 doesn't allow it**, i think this is what is making the webpack unable to find the files, because while searching for the files, it concatenates * at the end of the file and output "unable to find file". and also if I add the correct extension to the any of the entry files, it fails to find them.
I even tried to open git bash with "as admin" option thinking that it might be a rights issue, same error.

EDIT: added project structure image.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you got `babel-preset-env` install as a dev dependency ?

Comment: yes,     "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",

Comment: Have you tried creating `.babelrc` in the root directory where your `webpack.config.js` is and give it a `{
  "presets": ["react", "env"]
}`  delete `query: {...}` from `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Are `jquery` and `foundation-sites` packages stored under `node_modules` or did you create those two directories yourself in the root of your app? If they are installed via npm, then you need to add `/node_modules/` to the start of their paths. `/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`. And the path will be relative to where your `webpack.config.js` file is. Can you post your project structure?

Comment: I already have the file, and it has exactly what u typed, tried it with and w/o the query option for babel-loader. neither of them worked.

Comment: Looks like `path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min')` might work. Does webpack `resolve` work in the `entry` config like that? I haven't ever seen that.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I double checked the location for the modules, they all checkout, they're all inside node_modules, i didnt customize anything, here is the project structure https://i.imgur.com/mNnw0uP.png

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda , I added the path resolve to the entry files, same exact error

Comment: The missing files are not the ones in the entry, they're being added on their own by included packages, but webpack by force concatenates whatever is in resolve.extentions and then tries to find them.

Comment: `exclude: /node_modules/,` is probably the cause. Your resolve config and loaders are not correct.